# update only related products programatically - magento 2

Tags: magento2, product, magento2.0.8, product-linking

I follow this [answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/136406/36463) for update related products, It works but it will delete **cross sell** and **upsell** products of parent. is this default behavior or did I something wrong?

```
//For testing load one product

$target=$this->productRepository->getById(501);

//Here I collect related skus list programatically

.........................................
..........................................

$skuLinks = explode(",",$related);
$obj = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
foreach($skuLinks as $skuLink) {

    $productLink = $obj->create('Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductLinkInterface')
    ->setSku($target->getSku())
    ->setLinkedProductSku($skuLink)
    ->setPosition(1)
    ->setLinkType('related');
    $linkData[] = $productLink;

}

//Set Product Link
$target->setProductLinks($linkData);
$this->productRepository->save($target);

//checking, it only display the related skus, previously it shows related,upsell,crossell
$links=$target->getProductLinks();
foreach($links as $link)
{
    echo $link->getLinkType().' - '.$link->getLinkedProductSku().'<br>';
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All links will be overwritten, if you call ProductInterface::setLinks method.
You can try to add new links in already existed product links array.

*Example:*

```
$links = $product->getProductLinks();
$links[] = $newLink;
$product->setProductLinks($links);
$this->productRepository->save($product);
```

Comment: it make sense. I will test... :-)

Comment: you provide answer for add new product links, however for update/replace we need to preserve crosssell and upsell alone after that add related skus, finally overwrite. :-)

Comment: Please answer on this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/233321/function-override-issue-in-foreach-loop-while-importing-upsell-and-related-produ

Comment: not working, getting this error Call to a member function getLinkType() on array in /var/www/html/rectorsealwork/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/ProductRepository.php:451

Comment: Do you know if it's possible to just save only the related product attribute @Max, or better still, just the cross sell or just the upsell?

Answer (score 0):

The following code works for me. The code inserts product id and the related product ids directly to the database.

```
 try {
   $q = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
   $q->getConnection('core_write')->query("insert into catalog_product_link (linked_product_id, product_id,link_type_id) values (".$newRelatedProdId.",".$newProdId.",1)");

                    }
                    catch(Exception $e)
                    {
                        echo 'Duplicate Key'.PHP_EOL;
                    }
```

Please refer the below links for the further details.
https://www.pearlbells.co.uk/programmatically-assign-related-products-magento-2/