# Magento 2: Upsell programmaticly add products only adds last item

Tags: magento2, product, catalog, up-sells, product-linking

I am trying to add upsell products automaticly with the `Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductLinkInterfaceFactory` class, I added following code:

EDIT CODE IS UPDATED WITH AN WORKING EXAMPLE

```
        $i = 100;

        foreach ($collection as $item) {
            $productLink = $this->productLinkInterfaceFactory->create();
            $productLink->setSku($product->getSku())
                ->setLinkedProductSku($item->getSku())
                ->setPosition($i++)
                ->setLinkType('upsell');

            $linkData[] = $productLink;
        }

        if ($linkData) {
          $product->setProductLinks($linkData);
          $product->save();
        }
```

I tried solving it with the following similar post: [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/136359/set-related-upsell-products-programatically-only-works-for-1-product)

But no result. 
It only adds the last product, anybody knows how to add all products?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove  `$linkData[] = $productLink;` and instead do `$product->setProductLinks($linkData);` , I think  there is  problem with the scope of `$linkdata[]` .

Modified code ;

```
$productLink = $this->productLink;
    foreach ($collection as $item) {
            $productLink->setSku($product->getSku())
                ->setLinkedProductSku($item->getSku())
                ->setPosition($i++)
                ->setLinkType('upsell');
        }

        if ($linkData) {
          $product->setProductLinks($productLink);
          $product->save();
        }
```

**EDIT ;**

Try your code only but define the `$linkData` beforehand (scope outside the loop too) , also we need to create new object of `Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductLinkInterface` for each loop iteration

```
$linkData = [];     
        foreach ($collection as $item) {
            $productLink = $this->productLink->create(); // we need to create new object for each loop iteration
            $productLink->setSku($product->getSku())
                ->setLinkedProductSku($item->getSku())
                ->setPosition($i++)
                ->setLinkType('upsell');

            $linkData[] = $productLink;
        }

        if ($linkData) {
          $product->setProductLinks($linkData);
          $product->save();
        }
```

Comment: Thanks! It returns PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor::setProductLinks() must be of the type array or null, object given

Comment: I have  updated the code , check the EDIT section

Comment: Yeah, I saw that in the other post, just tried it and no result.... Count function returns 8 but still only showing the last item

Comment: I have edited more code in edit , please check again