# Magento 2 : How to assign related product to main product programatically

Tags: magento2, catalog, related-products

Is their any way can we assign multiple related products to a product ?

for example i have to assign from a csv row

```
Main SKU, SKU #1, SKU #2,  SKU #3,  SKU #4
p226944, p210881, p213312, p218070, p228407
```

Comment: Check this link: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/136359/set-related-upsell-products-programatically-only-works-for-1-product

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Hello, @AmitSaini i have created & runned script it runs successfully.
But in product & on frontend i do not see related product linked.

Comment: Any thoughts what can be the issue ?
Is it reindexing ?

Comment: Please check this link, hope it helps. https://gist.github.com/mrkhoa99/bd43fe34fc51d1f7fd38fbf7d13d384b

Comment: please first check in products admin. its assigned or not? if not then your code not working. and if assigned then just do re-idex via ssh/cmd.

Comment: Thanks for the program link @JayPipaliya

Comment: Hello, @GohilRajesh its not assigned, i have executed reindexing.

Comment: have you checked below answer?

Comment: Hello guys, this method does not work even after re-index i did not find any product assigned to main sku.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        $obj = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

        /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product */
        $productObject = $obj->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product');

        $product = $productObject->loadByAttribute('sku', 'Test Test');

        $linkDataAll = [];
        $skuLinks = "0012365,test1233,789456";
        $skuLinks = explode(",",$skuLinks);

        foreach($skuLinks as $skuLink) {
            //check first that the product exist
            $linkedProduct = $productObject->loadByAttribute("sku",$skuLink);
            if($linkedProduct) {
                /** @var  \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductLinkInterface $productLinks */
                $productLinks = $obj->create('Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductLinkInterface');
                $linkData = $productLinks //Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductLinkInterface
                    ->setSku($product->getSku())
                    ->setLinkedProductSku($skuLink)
                    ->setLinkType("related");
                $linkDataAll[] = $linkData;
            }

        }
        if($linkDataAll) {
            print(count($linkDataAll)); //gives 3
            $product->setProductLinks($linkDataAll);
        }
        $product->save();
```

try this code and if help you please accept as answer :)

dont use **objectmanager** this code just for reference

Comment: Hello, could you please tell me why you commented //        $product->save(); ?

Comment: Sorry..I updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks it works, i can see products assigned in related products grid but its not appearing on frontend.
any thoughts why ?

Comment: if its assigned in admin then almost you done. now if not visible in fronted then please check product visiblity is may be "Not Visible Individually" or product disable or out of stock

Comment: if it helps you please do upvote and mark as solution brother :)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, one thing is it adds new set of products
each time & remove old set of products from related products.
Any way to prevent it ?
Also execution also taking much time, any thoughts if it can be improved ? Thanks

Comment: please do reindex also if still not showing on frontend

Comment: Actually products are simple product. so they are set as not visible.

Comment: if you wanna prevent then before set please get products related products sku and add to array. and use array unique function for prevent duplicate loop.

Comment: Cool thanks, it uses foreach loop i am wondering if we direct pass an array to method to assign multiple sku without loop ?

Comment: execution time depend on server and also this code is lengthy but there are no other option for now. you can still try your way

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124462/discussion-between-gohil-rajesh-and-devhs).